# Add/update and display an array of meta_values

Tags: mysql, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to add an array of meta_values to a single meta_key and display them in a list like so:

- Assessment One, Passed
- Assesment Two, Passed

My code for updating/adding the user_meta:

```
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    $key = 'assessment_result';
    $assessment_name = get_the_title();
    $new_value = array($assessment_name, 'Passed');
    $meta = get_user_meta($user_id, $key, false);
    if ( ! array($meta) ) {
        $meta = array();
    }
    $meta[] = $new_value;
    update_user_meta($user_id, $key, $meta, $unique);
```

After completing two assessments, my array looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Assessment Two [1] => Passed ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Assessment One [1] => Passed ) ) ) 1
```

There seems to be too many arrays!

Then my query looks like this:

```
$user_assessment_results = get_user_meta($user_id, 'assessment_result', true);
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($user_assessment_results as $user_assessment_result) {
    echo '<li>';
    $output = array();
    foreach ($user_assessment_result as $result_item) {
        $output[] =  $result_item;
    }
    if( count( $output ) ) echo join( ", ", $output );
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Which results in:

- Array
- Assessment One, Passed

Can you suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: in the update code it's not `if ( ! array($meta) ) {` but `if ( ! is_array($meta) ) {`

Comment: Thanks, but I removed that if statement as it will always be an array, it didnt help anyway.  Changing False to True in get_user_meta seems to have sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem `$meta = get_user_meta($user_id, $key, false);` should have been `$meta = get_user_meta($user_id, $key, true);`